# How do I compile code for an OpenNTF customization?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes

Our bosses want to use the FileExplorer widget from OpenNTF so that they can drag emails to file system in order to share them with others. They already had a treasure trove of such messages in a different system, so using a shared Notes mail file was determined to be an unacceptable solution. They like FileExplorer, but are disappointed that emails get named with the subject line. They've requested a mod to prepend the filename with the FROM and DATE values.

I've written a modification to use in the CopyFileJob.java file and think that the following line in the copy method of the CopyFilesJob class will handle the renaming.

```
if (source.isFile()) {
    // only check about modifying filename if it's a file to copy
    final File dest = new File(fDest.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator  + modifyEmailFilename(source.getName()));
...
```

The code it calls is relatively simple, since the email file is formatted text.

```
    public static String modifyEmailFilename( String filename ) {
    try {

        int extensionCheck = filename.indexOf(".eml");
        if ( extensionCheck >= 0 ) { 

            String fromResult = "";
            String dateResult = "";
            String fromString = "From:";
            String dateString = "Date:";

            Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File (filename));

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                int searchIndex = nextLine.indexOf(fromString);
                if ( searchIndex == 0 ) {
                    int startIndex = nextLine.indexOf(":") + 2;
                    int endIndex = nextLine.indexOf("@");
                    fromResult = nextLine.toString().substring(startIndex,endIndex);
                }
                searchIndex = nextLine.indexOf(dateString);
                if ( searchIndex == 0 ) {
                    int startIndex = nextLine.indexOf(",") + 2;
                    int endIndex = nextLine.lastIndexOf(" ");
                    dateResult = nextLine.toString().substring(startIndex,endIndex).replace(" ","_").replace(":","");
                }               
            }

            return fromResult + "_" + dateResult + "_" + filename;
        }
        // when eml is not in the filename, just return the filename
        return filename;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage() );
        return "Error";
    }
    return "Finished";
}
```

What I can't figure out is how I'd re-compile this to implement my custom code and deploy it. Of course, I haven't been able to test it in place, because I can't figure out the steps to compile it when there are some many components to the OpenNTF project.

Answer (score 1):

David,
A sidebar plug-in in the Notes client has 2-3 Eclipse projects:

- a plug-in project
- a feature project
- an update site project

Features contain one or more plugins. Plugins can appear in more than one feature. Update sites contain one or more features. Features can appear in more than one update site.

It is confusing at best. But that's the Eclipse way. The OpenNTF project contains all source, so download it and import it into Domino designer ( or Eclipse) into the 2-3 projects. Mikkel Heisterberg and Nathan Freeman have articles how to setup Eclipse for Notes plugin development.

For general tutorials about plugin development check Lars Vogalla's tutorials.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Still kind of lost. I just setup Juno for Notes 9 by using Mikkel's directions http://lekkimworld.com/pages/eclipse42_notes9.html but I don't know what is meant by 'download the OpenNTF project'. Do you mean the FileExplorer project that I want to modify or something grander? Any links to something on their sites would be helpful as searches aren't pulling up a step-by-step guide (which may not exist).

Comment: The file explorer you want to modify. It contains the source code. You face 2 challenges: learn about plugin development in general and complete your changes. For the first check this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-multimedia/